# filling under step functions in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, fill

I am using Gnuplot to draw step functions from an input file:

```
plot 'myFile' using 1:2 with steps
```

I want to fill underneath the plot. something like

```
plot 'myFile' using 1:2 with filledcurves
```

But Gnuplot fill underneath the diagram by drawing a line between consecutive points.

How can I fill in underneath the step function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `fillsteps` plotting style, which is the same as `steps`, but the area between the curve and `y=0` is filled:

```
set samples 11
set xrange [0:10]
plot '+' with fillsteps fs solid 0.3 noborder lt 1,\
     '+' with steps lt 1 lw 4
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get border around each box?

Comment: @masfenix For borders use the `boxes` plotting style